# Is it possible to search for git commit message in many repositories in a git server?

Tags: git, version-control, repository

Is it possible to search for git commit message in many repositories on a git server?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The convenient way to go about this is to temporarily aggregate all the remotes in one repo.
Consider `REPO_LIST` as the array of (local) paths to the repositories on a git server:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/aggregate_repo && cd $_ && git init .
$ REPO_LIST=(/path/to/repo1 /path/to/repo2 /path/to/repoN); \
  for repo in ${REPO_LIST[@]}; do git remote add $(basename $repo) $repo; done
$ git fetch --all
$ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes | \
  while read ref; do git log --grep=SEARCH_PATTERN $ref --pretty=oneline; done | \
  sort | uniq
```

This will create an aggregate repo, add all the remotes to search, fetch the remotes, and then for each refname in every remote it will search for SEARCH_PATTERN, listing all the matching commits.